# comm_split strange behavior?

Tags: c, parallel-processing, multiprocessing, mpi

I have spent quite a few hours trying to figure this out so i have finally come here for some help. I am learning mpi and the problem is since i am new i don't know why some weird behavior occurs. What i am trying to do is i have 8 numbers spread across 8 processors as follows. Then i split the communicator then i exchange elements from the sub communicator as follows:

0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7

split

0 1 2 3 | 4 5 6 7

exchange

2 3 0 1 | 6 7 4 5

The output is 4 5 6 7 0 1 2 3 but the output should be 2 3 0 1 6 7 4 5. Can i get some help on why it is giving me this strange result?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <mpi.h>
#include <math.h>
int main(argc,argv)
int argc;
char *argv[];

{
    int myid, numprocs;
    int color,Zero_one,new_id,new_nodes;
    MPI_Comm NEW_COMM; 
    MPI_Init(&argc,&argv);
    MPI_Comm_size(MPI_COMM_WORLD,&numprocs);
    MPI_Comm_rank(MPI_COMM_WORLD,&myid);


    int my_num, my_received;

       int old_id;


    switch(myid){

        case 0:
            my_num = 0;
            old_id = 0;

        break;


        case 1:
            my_num = 1;
            old_id = 1;

        break;

        case 2:
            my_num = 2;
            old_id = 2;

        break;

        case 3:
            my_num = 3;
            old_id = 3;

        break;

        case 4:
            my_num = 4;
            old_id = 4;

        break;

        case 5:
            my_num = 5;
            old_id = 5;

        break;

        case 6:
            my_num = 6;
            old_id = 6;

        break;

        case 7:
            my_num = 7;
            old_id = 7;

        break;


    }

//here i split

    color=myid % 2;
    MPI_Comm_split(MPI_COMM_WORLD,color,myid,&NEW_COMM);
    MPI_Comm_rank( NEW_COMM, &new_id);
    MPI_Comm_rank( NEW_COMM, &new_nodes);



  //here i exchange in the sub list or communicator

        if(new_id < 2){

            MPI_Send(&my_num, 1, MPI_INT,  2 + new_id, 0, NEW_COMM);
            MPI_Recv(&my_received, 1, MPI_INT, 2 + new_id, 0, NEW_COMM, MPI_STATUS_IGNORE);         

        }
        else
        {
            MPI_Recv(&my_received, 1, MPI_INT, new_id - 2, 0, NEW_COMM, MPI_STATUS_IGNORE);         
            MPI_Send(&my_num, 1, MPI_INT, new_id - 2 , 0, NEW_COMM);


        }



    printf("old_id= %d received num= %d\n", old_id, my_received);


    MPI_Finalize();

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Running your program I get:

```
old_id= 4 received num= 0
old_id= 5 received num= 1
old_id= 1 received num= 5
old_id= 3 received num= 7
old_id= 6 received num= 2
old_id= 7 received num= 3
old_id= 0 received num= 4
old_id= 2 received num= 6
```

According to your split, all even ranks are collected in one communicator and all odds in another:

```
old_id= 0 received num= 4
old_id= 2 received num= 6
old_id= 4 received num= 0
old_id= 6 received num= 2
```

and:

```
old_id= 1 received num= 5
old_id= 3 received num= 7
old_id= 5 received num= 1
old_id= 7 received num= 3
```

Which looks like the thing you asked for. Either I can't reproduce your problem, misunderstood it or nothing is wrong?

Comment: yes that is the output i am getting as well. Basically old_id is the id of the processor and received num is the number received after exchange. Ignoring the processor id, the received num should be 2 3 0 1 6 7 4 5 meaning 2 is the received num for proc 0, 3 is received num for proc 1, 0 received num for proc 2 etc.

Comment: Why do you think the result should be like this? According to your code, I'd expect the output you are getting. As I said, you gather all even ranks into one communicator and all odd ones into another. You maintain the original order, thus your one communicator ends up with 0,2,4,6 and the other one with 1,3,5,7. Then you tell each communicator to swap the content of the first two ranks with the last two, resulting in 4,6,0,2 on the one and 5,7,1,3. Your problem seems to be, that you want to have another splitting. Maybe use /4 instead of %2?